# Не работает функция подсчета слов в строке при работе с файлом

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Необходимо посчитать количество слов в каждой строке для дальнейших действий. Функция работает с обычной строкой, а вот при передаче ей буфера, в котором содержится ( или должна содержаться строка из файла) функция не работает и всё время возвращает 1. Вроде примитивное задание, но ошибку найти не могу. Стринги, пожалуйста, не предлагать.

Код:

```
int CountWords(char str[]) { 
    int counter = 0;
    char* c = strtok(str, " ");
    while (c) {
        c = strtok(NULL, " ");
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

void DeleteMaxWords(const char path[]) {//здесь ищу строку с макисмальным количеством слов 
    ifstream f(path);
    char buf[50];
    int i = 0;
    int _strNum = 0;
    int _maxWords = 0;
    while ( !f.eof() ) {
        f.getline(buf, 50);
        if (CountWords(buf) > _maxWords) {
            cout << CountWords(buf) << endl;
            _maxWords = CountWords(buf);
            _strNum = i;
        }
        ++i;
        //cout << _maxWords << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из описания [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok):

> This function is destructive: it writes the '\0' characters in the
>   elements of the string str. In particular, a string literal cannot be
>   used as the first argument of strtok.

Соответственно, пробелы становятся '\0' и второй проход читает только одно слово. Как исправить? Вызвать один раз перед if и записать в переменную и дальше использовать переменную, да и зачем вызывать алгоритм 10 раз подряд, когда можно только 1 раз.
К тому же есть ещё одно ошибка.

Неправильно:

> ```
> while ( !f.eof() ) {
>     f.getline(buf, 50);
>     ...
> }
> ```

Потому что f.eof() будет true только **после** попытки чтения, когда конец файла был достигнут.

```
while (f.getline(buf, 50)) {
    int k = CountWords(buf);
    if (k > _maxWords) {
        cout << k << endl;
        _maxWords = k;
        _strNum = i;
    }
    ++i;
    //cout << _maxWords << endl;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за  развернутый ответ, как интересно получилось с вызовом функции, то есть получается, в моем варианте if( CountWords(buf) > _maxWords ) моя функция упирается в пробел, а в вашем - нет. Честно говоря, к своему стыду, так толком и не понял почему.

Я понял, что strtok, после нахождения лексемы ставит нуль-символ, а дальше что-то ума не хватает состыковать с результатами.

Comment: @Tovarisch первый раз функция работает нормально, но заменяет все пробелы в buf на нуль символ. А strtok() работает до конца нуль символа  Вызывая опять эту функцию на этот буфер, strtok будет видеть только одно слово

Comment: Я понял! При втором вызове функции, когда я хочу просто вывести значение, моя строка уже изменена, содержит нуль-символы вместо пробелов, спасибо ещё раз, всех благ!